# I can't get the @ActionLink to render the correct url to work with my MVC3 default routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, razor

I'm trying to take advantage of the default routing so I get a URL without a query string parameter.

So, I've currently got this url:

```
 http://www.mysite.Items/Edit?ItemID=19719
```

And I'm trying to get a URL like this:

```
 http://www.mysite.Items/Edit/19719
```

The routing works, but I can't get the @Html.ActionLink method to produce the 2nd url.

Here is my razor code:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {item.ItemID}, new { id = "edit-" + item.ItemID })
```

The first argument is my link's text. The 2nd argument is the Action. 3rd is the ID Value and finally the last argument is and HTML attribute I use for some javascript I'm using.

Originally I had my 3rd Argument as

```
  new {itemID = itemID}
```

This was when my Edit action expected an integer value named itemID as the parameter. I changed it to 'id' so the routing would work.

Ideally I would like a route that would pass the 19719 value to an action with the argument named itemID, but this is beyond the scope of this question.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**
Thanks [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) for this solution.

I ended up leaving my html code and action arguments the way I had them originally.  All that was really required was an update to my routes.  I should note that I had to add my new route map before the default.  Anyway, here is my route registration now that made this all work.

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("", "Items/{action}/{itemID}", new { controller = "Items", action = "Details", itemID = @"\d+" });
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );           
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default routes uses `id` as route token name, so you want:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit", 
    "Edit", 
    new { id = item.ItemID }, 
    new { id = "edit-" + item.ItemID }
)
```

Notice **`new { id = item.ItemID }`** and not `new {itemID = itemID}` and not `new {item.ItemID}`.

Comment: Wow , Darin Dimitrov answered you :D
Lucky dude

Comment: he rarely misses any question under the `.net` tag `;)`

Comment: is it possible to register a route that would allow itemID as the parameter? Something like:   routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", itemID = UrlParameter.Optional } );

Comment: @JeffReddy, yes simply replace id by itemId: `routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{itemId}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", itemId = UrlParameter.Optional });`. Now your controller actions should take `itemId` as parameter instead of `id`.